# How to tell Postgresql what tables will be in a transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-12, blocking

RDS Postgresql 12.12

`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_foo ON foo (f1, f2, f3);` is blocked by a stored procedure which only touches tables `bar` and `baz`.

`BEGIN` and `START TRANSACTION` don't seem to have a clause which lets one specify only the tables which are touched in the transaction.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are under the misconception that PostgreSQL locks tables that are not related to the active transaction. That is not the case. If a transaction has a lock on table `foo`, one of the statements in the transaction *did* affect the table `foo`.

Note that statements can affect tables that are not mentioned in the statement. One possibility would be a trigger on a table you modify: statements in the trigger function can modify other tables. Another example would be a cascading delete caused by a foreign key constraint.

I recommend that you keep your transactions short, then the lock will be less of a problem.

There is no way to tell PostgreSQL *not* to lock a table that is used or a column that is modified in a transaction. That would lead to inconsistencies in the database.

Comment: If I specify "this transaction only touches tables A, B, and C", but a trigger actually also touches table D, then the blame is on me for not also specifying table D. No, I don't think there's *locking* involved.  The CREATE INDEX was, though, without a doubt, **blocked** by the CALL statement.

Comment: And yes, yes, we all know that transactions must be kept short.  That's not always possible, though, when a huge and complicated (government regulations are complicated, which means large, complicated stored procedures), there's lots of data, and it's not always neatly and uniformly distributed across every index key.  **Users do stupid things** that screw things up, and make Postgresql decide that sequential scans are The Right Thing to do.

Comment: Because of those hairy complicated government regulations, WHERE clause predicates are required against unindexable values (just a few values, and usually something like `WHERE foo IS NULL OR foo != 1`, when the only three values are NULL, 0 and 1.

Comment: Believe it or not, calling a procedure does not block `CREATE INDEX`. You can figure out what exactly the problem is by looking at the `pg_locks` view.